# Batch execution in Fitnesse

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

Is there any feature available for FitNeese where I can create batch of tests and run such multiple batches automatically?

Note :- I want to execute these tests in the same test suite.

Problem is - My every single test has a web service call  , and if I add more than 100 tests at a time then the response is never returned.
Currently using FitNesse SLIM.

I am new to FitNeese. Please advice.

Comment: I am able to solve this problem to some extent. I have created a Test Suite and created some test pages in that suite as batches.I am adding my tests breaking into those batches .So in one click I am able to execute all the tests batch by batch.

Comment: Current problem is I am not able to execute more than 100 tests on FitNesse. Broweser shows connection disconnected after some time if I add more than 100 tests in a single test page.

Comment: I run more than 100 tests quite often. Does the test not start at all, or do you get any empty page, or ..?